# Python : Outer join or merge of two dataframes gives the error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge, typeerror

I am joining the two dataframes digiplay_video_services_t and dsr_conflict_df.

```
common_cols = ['region', 'management_area', 'rf_line_up_name', 'site', 'frequency_name', 'sdv_site', 'bandwidth_spectrum_width', 'qam_rf_label']

dsr_digiplay_conflicts = pd.merge(digiplay_video_services_t, dsr_conflict_df,
left_on = common_cols + ['reference_lcm_name', 'dwnstrm_plant', 'frequency', 'eia', 'source_id'], 
right_on = common_cols + ['reference_lcm_name', 'dwnstrm_plant', 'frequency', 'eia', 'source_id'], how = 'outer', indicator = True)
```

I am getting the following error and  stack trace is given here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task_3_build_wt_video_services.py", line 1141, in <module>
    main()
  File "task_3_build_wt_video_services.py", line 624, in main
    how = 'outer', indicator = True)
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 89, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 668, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 884, in _get_join_info
    (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 863, in _get_join_indexers
    self.left_join_keys, self.right_join_keys, sort=self.sort, how=self.how
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1328, in _get_join_indexers
    zipped = zip(*mapped)
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1326, in <genexpr>
    for n in range(len(left_keys))
  File "/var/lib/airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1974, in _factorize_keys
    rlab = rizer.factorize(rk)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable.pyx", line 96, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Factorizer.factorize
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1880, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1787, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I am using Python 3.6 and pandas 1.1.2.

Comment: Do any of the columns contain arrays?

Comment: I am adding code to check if any of the element in both the dataframe is an array. But my guess is they do not contain arrays

Comment: Do you know the `dtypes` of all columns?  With object dtype it's possible to have an isolated array (or list) in a column, but usually a column consists entirely of arrays.  One way or other **you** need to know the contents of the frames.  We can only guess.

Comment: I printed the dtypes of all the columns in both the dataframes.   I can see object data type.  I do not see any array type. I printed the contents of the frames but the data frames are huge.

'''

Answer (score 0):

This is my theory.

Pandas library is using hashed values of all indices and columns so you must provide it with immutable (hashable) variables But `np.array` is mutable (more on mutable and immutable [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/)). For checking if the variable is hashable or not

```
try:
    hash(the_varible)
except TypeError:
    print( "It's unhashable.")
else:
    print( "It's hashable.")
```

Comment: Thanks !!! So,  I would check all the  columns in both the dataframe  hashable.  Is there a peice of code how to check that ??

Comment: I use the following code fragments to  find the unhashable value. But it does not find anything.  '''for idx,  row in digiplay_video_services_t.iterrows():
        for i in columns:
               try:
                    hash(row.loc[i])
               except TypeError:
                   print("unhashable value : " +  str(row.loc[i]))'''.  Am I doing anything wrong ??

Comment: Did you chack the `dsr_conflict_df` against the above loop? @user1634050

Comment: I used the following code to find  empty arrays in the two data frames. I found empty arrays present in  dsr_conflict_df  dataframe and replaced that with None.  '''for col in cols2:
    for row in range(len(dsr[col])):
        if type(dsr[col][row]) == ndarray:
            print(col, row, dsr[col][row]) '''  I used the following lines of code to fix it.  '''dsr['qam_rf_label'] = dsr['qam_rf_label'].apply(lambda x: None if type(x) == ndarray else x)'''

Comment: Please add the portion of code and data which allows us to reproduce the error @user1634050